# Session management not working with Spring boot and Zuul proxy

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-session

I have zuul proxy connected to Spring boot services having sessions. Is Zuul a right fit for such a scenario?

Right now on each request in same browser, linked services are creating new sessions on page refresh.

I found few links to inject session id through a filter but did not work with Spring boot 2, Zuul 2 and tried using Spring session 2.0.,4 also.

Code added this to the filter

```
@Component
public class SessionSavingZuulPreFilter extends ZuulFilter {

@Override
public Object run() {

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
    List<String> cookies = 
         Collections.list(request.getHeaders("cookie"));
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    if (session != null && cookies.stream().noneMatch(c -> 
         c.startsWith("SESSION="))) {
        context.addZuulRequestHeader("cookie", "SESSION=" + session.getId());
    }
    if(session!=null)
        log.info("ZuulPreFilter session proxy: {}", session.getId());

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: This should be possible.  How do the services behind the Zuul proxy receive their sessions?  Via a cookie or via a header?

Comment: Not sure, with nginx it worked.

Comment: Got a reply here - https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/issues/488